# Is it possible to get a reference to a UIImage when capturing an image with UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

Right now I use the following to save a picture to my Photos album

```
-(void)shootPicture{
     [self.PickerController takePicture];
}
```

But I want to be able to get a reference to the UIImage rather than save it immediately to my camera roll.
Is there a way to achieve this in IOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set yourself as a `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and listen for `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` You get a Dictionary and get an `UIImage` by using the key `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`(or originalImage).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys